# Is there any tool that will make it dead-easy to quarter the size of an image (i.e., de-Retina it)?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-capture

Problem: when I take Screenshots on my retina mac using the built-in screen capture tool and attach them to certain tools (Outlook 2011, HipChat, etc.), they are enormous.

Usually to get around this problem, I'll resize them using Preview or I'll take the screenshots using Skitch.  But I'd love it if there was a way that I could simply select something from the right-click menu on the image and it would reduce the size to 1/4 (i.e., half the width).

Comment: What is the "default capture tool" in your eyes? Command Shift 4? Command 3?

Comment: Yeah, those two, though I use 4 much more than 3.

Comment: If you use Mail.app, when you attach an image it gives you the option to resize it. I've found that selecting the "large" size (as opposed to actual size) scales the image down to "non-retina" resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Automator

You can use OS X's **Automator.app** to quickly resize images to 1/4 of their original size. The Actions you want are:

- Get Selected Finder Items
- Scale Images

[image: Automator]

You can create [droplet like applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087148/how-to-make-a-droplet-on-mac-osx-with-automator) using Automator to make the whole process a single drag-and-drop. Alternatively you can [set up a folder action](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_folder_actions_automator) to resize any image dropped into a folder.

To learn more about using Automator, see Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488).

Comment: Even better, if you set this up as a service rather than a workflow, it'll be available through the right-click menu on any file. Just choose "Service" as the type when you create a new Automator document. You can also restrict services so they apply only to certain file types (images in this case).

Comment: Holy crud.  This is exactly what I needed!  I've created a folder called "shrunk" on my Desktop, and anything I want quarter-sized I simply move into that folder before attaching it in Outlook or similar.  It's about the same effort as a right-click option, and slightly less effort than dragging it into an app, and quite a bit less effort than Skitch or RetinaCapture.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [RetinaCapture](http://www.retinacapture.com/).
A free tool which allows you to take a "regular" smaller size screenshot instead of Retina screenshot. You can even pick retina, standard detail or both at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite what I'm looking for. It turns a `keypress, drag+click` process into an `open application, select, click, drag+click, save` process.  Plus the built-in screen capture has the added benefit of leaving hover state intact for a couple of seconds, which this and Skitch do not.